# What does the determinant of a homography matrix represent?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, determinant

I am trying to find one image (needle) within another (haystack). I am using the following OpenCV method, which first matches keypoints with SIFT and then applies homography:

https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_feature_homography/py_feature_homography.html

I noticed that when the needle isn't in the haystack I can still get a very large number of matched keypoints, almost as many as when it is found. However the determinant of the homography matrix is several orders of magnitude smaller, a very clear distinction.

Why is that?